# Can we use a DbContext within a Linq Select Expression?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it a good practice or a convention to use dbContext within a Select linq query as following . If not what is the right convention or alternative to do so ?

```
 dbContext.Employees.Select(x=>{
       **Name = dbContext.ContactInformation.Where(y=>y.Id = x.Id),**
        Id = x.Id
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you have a navigationPropery from Employee to ContactInformation? [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

```cs
var result = dbContext.Employees.Include(e => e.ContactInformation);
```

You can also use a Join.

```
var res = dbContext.Employees.Join(ContactInformation,
                 e => e.Id,
                 c => c.Id,
                 (e, c) => new { e, c })
           .Select(ec => ec.e);
```